How do I capture Bluetooth 5 Extended Advertising messages (Beacon) in real-time on MacOS (Macbook M2)?
I'm trying to capture Bluetooth 5 Extended Advertising messages (Beacon) from a nearby special purpose device, which broadcasts every second. It's a small message, only a primary advertisement packet (less than 50 bytes), but in the Bluetooth 5 Extended Advertising format (there's an extended header in it).
On my Macbook Air M2 (2022 Model running MacOS Sonoma 14.5), I'm running a small Swift application that uses the CoreBluetooth framework and essentially the CBCentralManager.scanForPeripherals method to listen for the above advertisement messages. All I'm doing right now is simply printing the messages.
What I expected is that the messages would also faithfully print out every second, but they don't. There's a large startup delay and even after that messages are printed in a sometimes bursty, sometimes regular way, but never once per second, at best once every 3 seconds.
I have tried many things but nothing helps: Being right next to the device, always flushing any buffer I can find in code, killing every single app on my computer except this one, and several other Chatgpt suggestions too, but the behavior remains the same. I have an app on my IPhone that does see the same messages every second though, and as I understand it, it must be using the same CoreBluetooth framework, but for iOS.
Is it that the Phone's OS is simply built to be more responsive to Bluetooth messages? And the Macbook is good after an actual Bluetooth connection is made, but is weaker on promptly scanning for the initial advertising messages? Any suggestions much appreciated!

Can you please share your code (especially the scanning part)?
